# Start Date and End Date in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two date fields which are `Start Date` and `End Date` for a Project.

If a user selects `start date` less then today and didn't select `EndDate`, I need to display the project as **on going**. How could I do that?

I am using following code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
onClose: function (dateText){
    if (dateText === "") {
        $( "#to" ).value("on going");
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Your complete code would be like:

```
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    },
    onClose: function (dateText){
       if (dateText === "") {
           $( "#to" ).value("on going");
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention you should but this into the $( "#to" ).datepicker options.

Comment: According to the Datepicker API is the date (String) returned by the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using Jquery UI datepicker. If yes, in that plugin you have an option **Select a date range**. It will restrict the selection of dates.

Check this [Jquery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Comment: Edwin.. i want to show on going if user doesn't select any date in ENDdate